# Getting the date when selecting the same flag 4 times in a row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have been presented with a problem, given three columns, customer ID, flag and date, where the flag resembles a country flag, for example USA. What I want to do is if a customer selects the same flag 4 times in a row, I want to get that customer ID, and date when he selected the same flag 4 times in a row.

This is my attempt at a solution:

```
Declare @SameFlagCount AS int = 0
Declare @currentFlag NVARCHAR(50)
Declare @nextFlag NVARCHAR(50)

SET @currentFlag = (Select Flag, customerID from FlagTable where countryName = ‘UK’)

While (@SameFlagCount < 4)
Begin
    Set @nextFlag= (Select Flag, customerID
    From FlagTable
    Where countryName = “etc”)
IF (@currentFlag = @nextFlag)
        Set @SameFlagCounter = @SameFlag + 1
        Set @currentFlag = @nextFlag
        Continue;
    IF (@SameFlagCount = 4)
        Select customerID, Date
        From FlagTable
    Else
        Continue;
End
```

But I have been told this is too complex and I need to come up with a simpler solution using a mathematical function. I cannot imagine such a solution on my own.

Can someone provide me with insights at a simpler solution?

Thank you

EDIT:

I'll try to provide sample data, problem is it was a really vague specification: INSERT INTO FlagTable ( customerID, Flag, Date) VALUES (1, "UK",  4-10-2005), (2, "Us",  3-7-2005), (3, "INDIA",  22-4-2005). And I guess the desired result would be Customer ID 5 for example selected flag US on 3-7-2005

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'll try to provide sample data, problem is it was a really vague specification:

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. You've given us a query and added an `insert` statement, but we still don't have DDL for the table. Your sample data with three rows is unlikely to have anything "4 times in a row", so it really doesn't illustrate the problem effectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select ft.*
from (select ft.*,
             lead(date, 3) over (partition by customerid order by date) as date_3,
             lead(date, 3) over (partition by customerid, flag order by date) as date_flag_3,
      from flagtable ft
     ) ft
where date_3 = date_flag_3;
```

The idea is to look at the date three rows ahead for each customer.  Then look at the date three rows ahead for each customer and flag.  If the dates are the same, all the intervening dates have the same flag.